# Overriding a class's method definition

Tags: python

Let's say I have a class, FooClass, that has a method, foo_method, defined. This class is in a third party library, and I want to explicitly override it. I have a number of classes that inherit from FooClass, so I don't want to override foo_method for every single subclass. Instead, I'd like to override the class's method definition without digging into the third party library code. When I try the obvious way,

```
from thirdparty import FooClass

class FooClass(object):

  def foo_method():
    newstuff
```

I get strange behavior -- NotImplementedErrors and such. Am I missing something?

Comment: I think you need to be clearer what you mean by "explicitly override it". Do you mean, change how `foo_method` works everywhere it is used (even for uses entirely within the `thirdparty` module)? Or do you mean, change how `foo_method` works, but only for certain instances of `FooClass` that I create. For the first, use a "monkey patch", as in Martijn Pieters's answer. For the second, use inheritance, as in Osh's answer.

Comment: @Blckknght What do you mean by _"uses entirely within the ``thirdparty`` module"_ ? The ``thirdparty`` module isn't imported.

Comment: @eyquem: I mean that if some other code imports `thirdparty` and calls `thirdparty.do_stuff()` which creates some `FooClass` instances, should those instances get the changed `foo_method` behavior? They will if you monkey patch, and won't if you inherit. Of course, this may be irrelevant if there is no such other code (and you know there never will be) or if there are no functions in the `thirdparty` module that creates `FooClass` instances.

Comment: @Blckknght With _"if some other code imports thirdparty"_ , do you mean another part in the general code in which ``from thirdparty import FooClass`` is written ? that is to say in the same script ?

Comment: @eyquem: Probably code in a different module. Usually you won't have another import of the `thirdparty` module in the same place you had a `from thirdparty import FooClass`. If your program has many modules though, it's not uncommon for something like `thirdparty` to be imported several times in different ways places. So to restate my point: If your program only has one module that uses `FooClass` or if you want other modules to be able to go on using the regular implementation, use inheritance. If you have multiple modules and want to override `foo_method` for all of them, use a monkey patch.

Comment: @Blckknght OK now. _"Usually you won't have another import of the thirdparty module in the same place you had a from thirdparty import FooClass"_ : it's the reason why I was troubled, I didn't think to other modules doing their own operations, I am not accustomed to complex programs. Thank you for your patience. I upvote for two of your most upvoted answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are redefining the class locally; that won't change the original class or affect anyone using it elsewhere.

You *can* monkeypatch the method on the class:

```
from thirdparty import FooClass

orig_foo_method = FooClass.foo_method

def new_foo_method(self):
    # do new stuff
    # perhaps even call orig_foo_method(self)

FooClass.foo_method = new_foo_method
```

Now any code that tries to call `.foo_method()` on instances of `FooClass` anywhere in your Python interpreter will find and call your `new_foo_method()` method instead.

Comment: This works tolerably well - I've done it before. But note that anyone doing this will need to make sure that the patching module is loaded (or the patching code is otherwise invoked) before any attempt to use the patched class

Comment: @Marcin: absolutely; and any code storing a reference to the original *method* (bound or otherwise) won't see the patched new method either.

Comment: That will also include any *instances* which have had this method patched. I guess that's uncommon, but possible if anyone gets patch-crazy.

Comment: You also have to be very careful with pickling/unpickling and other object persistance. It can be especially painful when some library tries to implement the "fluent interface" pattern, and so all the methods that mutate and return mutated versions of the original class now also have to be overridden just to ensure the monkeypatch still exists after each call in the chain.

Comment: @Marcin: You mean instances that have a function or method object stored in the same name in the instance dictionary? Yes, those won't see a patched method on the class either. We are moving further away from likely scenarios here.

Comment: @EMS: Pickling *never* includes the class or the methods. Only a (string) reference to the class is stored with a pickle.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's my point. If you monkeypatch, you can't count on the monkeypatched method to exist after loading from Pickle or whatevever. Contrary to this being a rare concern, it happens to me often when trying to monkeypatch new methods onto Pandas.DataFrame in the pandas library. The various ways to persist a DataFrame don't bring back monkeypatched methods for the very reason you give. And if you naively just subclass DataFrame and override or define a new desired method, Pandas use of the fluent interface leads to constructed regular DataFrames that drop the monkeypatched stuff

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, that's what I mean. As I say, it's mostly a risk if people go patching-mad. It's not a problem with the technique in your answer *per se*, more a warning to the unwary that too much patching will be unpredictable.

Comment: @MartijnPieters With your last sentence , do you mean _"Now any code, **that executes in a particular 'run instance' of the interpreter**, that tries to call .foo_method() on instances of FooClass **anywhere in this particular 'run instance' of the Python interpreter** will find and call your new_foo_method() method instead."_ ?

Comment: @MartijnPieters What is the justification/need to write the instruction ``orig_foo_method = FooClass.foo_method``, please ?

Comment: @eyquem: That is the very very verbose version of what I meant, yes.

Comment: @eyquem: To keep a reference to the *old* method so you can call it in `new_foo_method` if desired. If you don't want to call the old implementation that line is not needed.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thank you. I know it is verbose. But as a French having some difficulties to fully understand english and as a medium pythonista conscious that Python has some subtleties, I prefer to eradicate my doubts even with medium-witted questions.

Comment: @MartijnPieters _"If you don't want to call the old implementation that line is not needed."_ It seemed that it was like that, but I wanted to be sure. I thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The first thing that comes to mind is to use simple inheritance ala

```
from thirdparty import FooClass

class MyUpdatedClass(FooClass):

  def foo_method():
    newstuff
```

Comment: This won't update any third-party code trying to import `FooClass` elsewhere.

Comment: However, if all of the code which uses FooClass is in subclasses, this is much better than monkeypatching.

Comment: Such third-party code should be replaced by more careful use of `MyUpdatedClass`. It's *wrong* and *very bad* to both have monkeypatching going on and also derive from the class post monkeypatching. This is the "right" answer IMO, and implies that all other uses of `FooClass` need to be changed to accommodate this (yes, even in large projects with lots of already existing unit tests, etc., relying on regular `FooClass`).

Comment: @EMS That won't solve the problem if you want to modify the behaviour of code you didn't write. There's definitely a place for monkeypatching, and it's here, when used with care and consideration.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. In that case use an adapter or proxy pattern, but still maintain your subclass of `FooClass` for the case where you wish you had instances of `FooClass` that just had differently defined methods (or extra methods). It still seems better than monkeypatching.

Comment: oldClass = FooClass to keep the old one. Then create a new class FooClass inheriting from FooClass

Comment: @EMS Adapter pattern also won't affect code that doesn't use your adapter.

Comment: But since, by definition of creating an Adapter for the third-party code, the third party code is used through the Adapter, this won't be a problem.

Comment: @EMS No. Adapter will not intercept calls from one piece of third-party code to another piece. Monkey-patching will.

Comment: Perhaps we should [taboo the words](http://lesswrong.com/lw/nu/taboo_your_words/) "monkeypatch" and "Adapter", because calling 3rd party code and intercepting its potential side-effects so that it functions according to a different interface than it does natively within the third party library is *exactly* what I would use the [Adapter pattern](https://designpatternslibrary.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Adapter%20Pattern) for.